# Cannot rename folder under C:\users\%username%\source\repos

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, locked-files

**Background:** Installed Visual Studio 2017 community. I ended up with a folder where new projects were created by default in `C:\users\%username%\source\repos`.  I'm guessing this folder is created by default for the Visual Studio Git integration.

But I don't not want any source control for projects in this directory.  So I removed the `.git` folder that resided under `C:\users\%username%\source\repos` thinking/hoping this will remove all traces Git source control for all the files under this folder.  But I now have problems renaming folders in this directory.

From Windows Explorer I can initially rename a folder but if I try to rename it again then I then I get a "The action cannot be completed because the folder is open in another program".  If I wait a few minutes then I'm able to rename the folder again.

I'm taking a guess that remnants of Git are still affecting this folder.  Do I need to take some other steps to remove all traces of Git from this directory?

I try identify what is locking the directory using this process but nothing comes up:

1. Open resource monitor
2. Open the CPU tab in the monitor
3. Select all processes (not sure if this is needed, you can probably just
4. search for the handle)
5. Expand "associated handles"
6. Search for the file you need
7. Close the process that has the handle